# Kotlin avoid smart cast for null check

Tags: kotlin

So I'm trying to reduce this code and avoid the smart cast hint from IDE.
The idea is I have a `nullable` variable of type `T` and I want to either map it to `R` or I just get `R` from a supplier in case the variable is `null`.

I've tried different approaches and came up with this one. Still it gives me the smart cast hint.

```kotlin
fun <T, R> T?.func(mapper: (T) -> R, supplier: () -> R): R =
    when(this) {
        null -> supplier()
        else -> mapper(this) // smart cast
    }
```

But I don't like the need for wrapping one of the lambdas in parenthesis. For example.

```kotlin
fun foo(value: String?): Int =
    value.func({ it.length + 20}) { 30 }
```

This may seem odd but the ideia in my context was to pass the variable as not `nullable` to a function that produced a `R` or call a function that generated a `R`.

```kotlin
fun bar(value: T?): R =
    when(value) {
        null -> func1()
        else -> func2(value) // smart cast
    }
```

Note: I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885684/kotlin-smart-cast-with-nullable-variable) but its not the same.

Comment: what do you mean by `avoid smart cast`? for what purpose?

Comment: The question isn't clear for me, are you asking in context of `smart cast` or the `wrapping of the lambda in parenthesis`? And btw you can always wrap both the lambda in the parenthesis for better readability than taking one outside. Taking trailing lambda outside is recommended when there is only 1 lambda in last parameter.

Comment: If `mapper` was a method of `T`, then you could reduce the code as `(this?.mapper())?:supplier()`.

Comment: Im asking in context to both is there any better way to do this avoiding the smart cast and make it better for readability?

Comment: @Venkatesh-PrasadRanganath ya i taught about that and that solves both but the mapper isn't a method of `T` unfortunately.

Comment: I re-read your question multiple times and it's still not clear what you're asking about. If you're bothered by having to wrap lambdas in parentheses, then you can declare a function and pass in a function reference instead of a lambda. If your question is about something else - please try providing more clarity. Also, avoid mixing multiple questions in one, prefer just posting multiple questions

Comment: What is the point in avoiding the smart cast? It’s not a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should avoid the smart cast hint

```
fun <T, R> T?.func(mapper: (T) -> R, supplier: () -> R): R {
    return this?.let { mapper(it) } ?: supplier()
}
```

Comment: I am still really curious about the reason for avoiding the smart cast. This is so much less readable.